# What does “Multiply keyword lists to get new keyword ideas” do in the new keyword planner tool?

Tags: google, keywords, google-ads

Does any body know? What does "Multiply keyword lists to get new keyword ideas" do in the new keyword planner tool?

Please see the attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google has [a help document that explains what the multiply keyword lists does](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2999770?hl=en):

> Save the time of manually combining keywords by multiplying two or more lists of keywords. Then, get historical statistics or traffic forecasts for the new list of combined keywords.
>
> ### Example
>
> Let's say you're advertising a chain of luxury resorts. You might have one keyword list of geographical locations and a second list of keywords that describe your resorts as follows:
>
> #### Keyword list 1
>
> - Mexico
> - Cabo
> - Cancun
>
> #### Keyword list 2
>
> - luxury resort
> - hotels
> - beach resort
>
> We'll combine the keywords from both lists to create new keyword phrases, like "Cabo hotels" or "Mexico luxury resort". Then, you can get traffic forecasts or historical statistics for these new keywords.